# Remapping Keys in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, capslock

i want to disable my Caps Lock key and move it to my Scoll Lock key.

The value of my Scancode Map is:

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03 00 00 00 00 00 3A 00
3A 00 46 00 00 00 00 00

This worked in Windows 8, but not 8.1.  What should I do?

Thanks.